# how do we translate 外資を含む in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-requests

Full text: このためには、都市部における経済活動のボトルネックになっている電力等の都市・産業インフラの脆弱性を抜本的に改善し、外資を含む製造業の立地環境を整備する必要がある。

My understanding: For this purpose, drastic improvements are required in the fragile and vulnerable urban industrial infrastructure such as electric power, which has become a bottleneck for economic activity in urban areas,   need to improve the environment

My issue: how do we translate 外資を含む in this sentence? is it foreign capital/ investment including the manufacturing industry or foreign capital embracing the manufacturing industry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, 外資を含む製造業 can be interpreted in two ways. The one is "the manufacturing industry that has foreign capital" and the other is "the manufacturing industry including foreign-affiliated companies". I think it means the latter because of the context. In this case, it is not necessary to limit the manufacturing industry to one that has foreign capital.

Comment: Yes, the latter makes more sense with the context. Thank you for helping me out!